# Difference between cr vs _cr

Tags: variables, odoo

which it is the difference between `cr` vs `_cr` and `uid` vs `_uid`,
also it appears as `self._cr` or `self._uid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all essentially the same, the difference is that passing cr and uid has been deprecated in odoo8, but those variables are still available for you to use but they are now considered private internal attributes of the class that's why they have  `_` before them take this for example

```
#old api
cursor = self._cr

#new api everything is contained in env (the environment)
self.env.cr


#api v7
def foo(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    #you can use cr here instead of self._cr because it is explicitly passed to the method

# api v8
def foo(self):
    # you don't need to pass in cr, uid, ids and context
```